# 451 4.5.0 SMTP protocol violation in basic java mail client

Tags: java, email, email-client

I have an assignment that requires me to build a very basic mail client to send an email on my school's server. If I open a command prompt on my computer and run telnet with these exact commands, the message goes through, but something in the program is causing it to kick back an error message. The exact response is:

451 4.5.0 SMTP protocol violation, see RFC 2821 e127si46647995qkb.26 - gsmtp

Here is the part of my code where I believe the issue to lie:

```
private void sendMessage(String from, String to, String subject, String msg) {
    Socket socket = null;
    DataOutputStream os = null;
    DataInputStream is = null;
    try {
        socket = new Socket("ALT3.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM", 25);
        os = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        is = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    } 
        if (socket != null && os != null && is != null) {
            try {

        os.writeBytes("HELO\n");    
        os.writeBytes("MAIL From: <" + from + ">\n");
        os.writeBytes("RCPT TO: <" + to + ">\n");
        os.writeBytes("DATA\n");
        os.writeBytes("From: <" + from + ">\n");
        os.writeBytes(subject);
        os.writeBytes(msg); // message body
        os.writeBytes("\n.\n");
        os.writeBytes("QUIT");

        String responseLine;
        while ((responseLine = is.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("Server: " + responseLine);
            if (responseLine.indexOf("Ok") != -1) {
              break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is the assignment to write an SMTP client, or just to send an email? If it's the latter, check out the JavaMail library.

Comment: SMTP and similar line-based protocols require lines to be terminated with CRLF. Does the problem persist if you terminate your lines with "\r\n" instead of "\n"?

Comment: Sorry, i thought I mentioned that. The assignment is to set up the SMTP client manually. It is for a networks class.

Comment: And I tried terminating that way just now and it didn't make any difference.

Comment: What are from, to, subject and msg?

Comment: Variables input by the user. They are exactly what they sound like, from is who the mail is from, to is who it is sending to, etc.

Comment: You need to check the server's reply after each SMTP command, unless you use the PIPELINING extension. A telnet session does get you the reply automatically, but your code just dumps the data in.

Comment: You need a newline after the final QUIT.

Comment: You should check the SMTP reply codes instead of looking for an "Ok" in the server replies. The server may or may not send the text "ok", and it may even send "this is not ok" and your code would not detect that as an error.